# State is not updating in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Below is my code snippet

```
 this.setState({
  isConfirmationDialogOpen: false,
  progress: Progress.Saving
});

let state = { ...this.state };
```

but it is not updating the state, can someone tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: please share some more code & describe more what you want to do .

Comment: yes. this.setState as async function.
You need to pay attention to this. use this.setState(()=> {},()=> {
 ... your code
})

or you can use useEffect in hook so that the problem is simplified

Comment: You can pass value of progress as a prop , and when the prop changes setState update it's value

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.setState({
  isConfirmationDialogOpen: false,
  progress: Progress.Saving
});

let stateData = { ...this.state };
```

Do not use the same name as state, also callback method in `setState` can be used to perform async activities.

UPDATE

If you don't want to use this callback, this is another way.

```
const state = {
    isConfirmationDialogOpen: false,
    progress: Progress.Saving
};

this.setState(state);
```

And use the `state` object but this won't guarantee that you've the latest state i.e. `this.state`

Comment: I need this state value on next call

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [this.setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is async.

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered.

If you are trying to access state and want the updated state, then because it is async you "HAVE TO" access it inside the callback function to ensure you access the state only after it has been updated.